# C++ specialized template inherit from non-specialized version

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates

I was trying to solve a problem, but found a different solution.
however out of curiosity like to know if the following is possible:

```
template< class > struct S;
template< > struct S< Foo > : struct< Foo > {};
```

I would like to be able to inherit nonspecialized struct from specialized struct.the example above does not work because the inherited struct is the specialized, leading to the infinite recursion.

One possible solution was to add second template parameter, say bool specialized, such that the default is false, and specialized template has that parameter is true.however that makes things a bit messy since instantiation needs to specify additional parameter.

Is there some other way around to implement the above?

the original problem was to implement matrix of matrixes, where matrix itself may have additional operators, depending if the constituent matrixes has those operators.I would hope that makes sense. at the same time different specialized matrix need to be of the same  base class at the same time retaining the same name, although with different template parameters. I have thought there might be a way to do it using enable_if and type traits

Comment: The first counter-question is what kind of problem are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 5):

You could keep all the generic stuff in a separate type, and extend that with your specialisation:

```
template <typename> struct S_generic { /* generic stuff here */ };

template <typename T> struct S : public S_generic<T> { /* nothing here */ };
template <> struct S<Foo> : public S_generic<Foo> { /* extra stuff here */ };
```

**Edit**: Alternatively, if you don't like the extra name, the way to use an extra flag without messiness when instantiating the template is to use a default value:

```
template <typename T, bool fully_defined=true> struct S;
template <typename T> struct S<T,false> { /* generic stuff here */ };

template <typename T> struct S<T,true> : public S<T,false> {};
template <> struct S<Foo,true> : public S<Foo,false> { /* extra stuff here */ };
```

Comment: this is what i ended up doing. what i was trying to avoid is having two different names. i think there might be a way to do it using enable_if and type traits.

Comment: There is no reason to add all the extra complication of enable_if or type traits, just use a common base that non-specialized and specialized can inherit from. `BlahBase` or `blah_base` are common.

Comment: at this point it is not so much practical question, as the matter of curiosity, "i wonder if it can do this?".

Comment: This is great technique. In some cases, with extra name you may also need to define extra ctors (not inheritted) or assignment operators in derived class. Template engine can generate this for you.

Answer (score 2):

> One possible solution was to add second template parameter, say bool specialized, such that the default is false, and specialized template has that parameter is true.however that makes things a bit messy since instantiation needs to specify additional parameter.

You can do `template<class Foo, bool flag = false>`, so the second parameter is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I like Mike Seymour's answer but you don't really have to specify true and false everywhere.

You can have something like this:

```
template<class T, bool = false>
class Object {
    void abstract_method();
};

// Now for your derived specialized type do this

template<>
class Object<SpecialObject> : Object<SpecialObject, true> { 
    // override any methods
};
```

We only need to default the `Object` template class `bool` to `false`, then when we instantiate a `Object<SpecialObject>()` it now has assigned to it the full type which is `Object<SpecialObject, false>` so now all we need to do is tell the compiler to find a potential different specialization that matches `Object<SpecialObject, true>` and we do that after the `:` above.

Now the compiler will choose the class with the `abstract_method` in it, even though it was defaulted to false, we already have chosen that specialization with `false` because of that default parameter when the compiler first encountered the type `Object<SpecialObject>` it is really the same as `Object<SpecialObject, false>`, so now when we pass `true` we are explicitly saying I don't care who took use of that default `false` parameter now try to find a different specialization using `true`, and it works.