# Can C++ templates check if a function has been overloaded for a given type?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, specialization, template-specialization

I have a template function that I expect to be templatized for different types at different places.
The problem is that I would like to know at compile time if there is an specialization for the given type to generate in 2 different ways another template.

```
template<typename T>
bool tobool(const T&){ throw Exception("Can't cast to bool");};
template<> bool tobool<bool>(const bool &value){ return value;}
```

I know you can test for function existance like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059880/c-specialized-template-inherit-from-non-specialized-version).

Any chance on how to test if tobool has been specialized?

Imagine that I want to generate a isbool() that returns true if tobool() has been specialized and returns false if not.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? : You want a metafunction which for each type T shows whether tobool has been specialized for T ?

Comment: Yep, I need to know if T is using generic or specialized tobool.

Comment: So at compile time you can check for its existance and do what with the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a (somewhat ugly and brittle) workaround, you could require specialization of a struct rather than a function and include a class constant to indicate whether the struct has been specialized:

```
template <typename T> 
struct ToBool {
   static bool tobool(const T&);
   static const bool specialized = false;
};
```

Another option is to only define `tobool` in specializations. That way, `ToBool<Foo>::tobool(f)` won't compile for any classes `Foo` that `ToBool` hasn't been specialized for.

As an alternative to `tobool`, you can use explicit conversion operators if you have control over the classes to be converted.

```
class Foo {
public:
    operator bool();
    ...
};
...
    Foo f;
    if (f) ...
```

If the type doesn't have a bool conversion (well, a conversion to a numeric or pointer type, both of which have standard conversions to bool), the program won't compile. Voila, compile time checking for a conversion.

If you don't want implicit conversion to bool, you can define an operator! and use a [double-bang](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safeboolP.html) for explicit conversion (though this isn't as readable):

```
class Foo {
public:
    bool operator!();
    ...
};

...
    Foo f;
    if (!!f) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific question is this: No, you cannot check whether T is using the primary or the specialized template. @Martin York's question is a very good one: why on earth would you want to check that? :)

Comment: Because there will be a class template<T> that has a method isbool() that has to return true if tobool<T> was specialized and false if it wasn't.